# Parse.com --- Raspberry PI SDK in python

Tags: parse-platform, raspberry-pi2, iot

I am newbie in IOT domain and have choose Parse for my backend needs. I want know is possible to write code in python and still use parse sdk for iot devices that natively supports C programs.

And i am planning to host Parse server on my private server.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is closing down. Choose another!

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: I have hosted Parse on my private server

Comment: Oh, might be worthwhile putting that within your query before you get hundreds more telling you exactly the same thing!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion